# Correct command to trace error with null safety turned off

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-android

I'm getting the following error in stack trace when I run:

> ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace --warning-mode all

in the android folder.

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:

- package:tinycolor
- package:open_iconic_flutter

When I do run using

> flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

in the project folder, I get a build fail error. However, in stack trace I'm unable to point out the stack trace when null safety is turned off since I don not know the right command. I tried

> ./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace --warning-mode all ----no-sound-null-safety

in the android folder, but it doesn't work.

What is the command to figure out the Build failure when null safety is turned off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter run -v`

-v stands for verbose. If you want to get all available commands run `flutter run -h`. -h will display help with all available commands

You can also run `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety -v`

Comment: @ Kaushik. Can you help me out here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72569552/android-exported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-element-serviceio-inter