# android: exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#io.intercom.android.sdk.fcm.IntercomFcmMessengerService>

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-manifest, intercom

I'm getting a Flutter build error in AndroidManifest.xml

> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#io.intercom.android.sdk.fcm.IntercomFcmMessengerService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
> explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined

There is no element called intercom in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I also added android:exported="true" in activity ".MainActivity" but the error still persists.

My AndoidManifest.xml file is as follows

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="social.myproject.app">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
            android:required="false" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>

        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
            android:label="myproject"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
        <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                android:value="2" />
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specify that the launch screen should continue being displayed -->
            <!-- until Flutter renders its first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <!-- Theme to apply as soon as Flutter begins rendering frames -->
            <meta-data
                    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                    android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="www.myproject.social"
                        android:pathPrefix="/api/auth/"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="www.myproject.io"
                        android:pathPrefix="/api/auth/"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The detailed error trace :

```html
 See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
[   +1 ms] E:\App Development\MyApp - Changes\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-16:19 Error:
[        ]      android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#io.intercom.android.sdk.fcm.IntercomFcmMessengerService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an
explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined



The error trace points to the following lines : 

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera"
            android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
            android:required="false"/>
```

EDIT: Updated the intercom version to 7.2.0. I get the follwing error now

> error: Instance member 'initialize' can't be accessed using static access. (static_access_to_instance_member at lib\services\intercom.dart:27)

The trace points to this line :

> await Intercom.initialize(appId,
> iosApiKey: iosApiKey, androidApiKey: androidApiKey);

My intercom.dart

```html
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:myproject/models/user.dart';
import 'package:myproject/services/user.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:intercom_flutter/intercom_flutter.dart';

class IntercomService {
  late UserService _userService;

  late String iosApiKey;
  late String androidApiKey;
  late String appId;

  void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    _userService = userService;
  }

  void bootstrap(
      {required String iosApiKey,
      required String androidApiKey,
      required String appId}) async {
    this.iosApiKey = iosApiKey;
    this.androidApiKey = androidApiKey;
    this.appId = appId;
    await Intercom.initialize(appId,
        iosApiKey: iosApiKey, androidApiKey: androidApiKey);
  }

  Future displayMessenger() {
    return Intercom.displayMessenger();
  }

  Future enableIntercom() async {
    await disableIntercom();
    User? loggedInUser = _userService.getLoggedInUser();
    if (loggedInUser == null) throw 'Cannot enable intercom. Not logged in.';

    assert(loggedInUser.uuid != null && loggedInUser.id != null);

    String userId = _makeUserId(loggedInUser);
    return Intercom.registerIdentifiedUser(userId: userId);
  }

  Future disableIntercom() {
    return Intercom.logout();
  }

  String _makeUserId(User user) {
    var bytes = utf8.encode(user.uuid! + user.id.toString());
    var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return digest.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Possibilities:

- Have you tried to do "Invalidate/Cache and Restart"?
- Have you tried to open the Project with the Android folder? It would display the errors if you missed anything in `AndroidManifest.xml.`
- You can also try with `flutter clean` & `flutter pub get` to run again.

### EDITED:

You have added some libraries and they haven't updated this service `IntercomFcmMessengerService` with `exported = true/false`

That's the reason why you are getting problems. You can do one thing that defines that service in your `<application>` tag with `exported=true`. It will override that service.

Comment: All three done. No effect.

Comment: Hello, added detailed error trace.

Comment: @Earthling Updated answer.

Comment: How do i define it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi. Edited question with details. Updated intercom version. Getting a 'static' error now.

Comment: @Earthling You have to call it with Class name, please check the example that has whole scenario.

Comment: Can you point out how pratik. I might be just nearing a solution with your help.

Comment: Solved it. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes even if we add android exported. A workaround will be to set the targetSdkVersion to 31 and compileSDKVersion to 31 in android->app->build.gradle file

Comment: both have been set to version 32 kaushik.

Comment: Please downgrade it to 31

Comment: Changed it to 31. Still the same error.

Comment: Have you used any package named intercom?

Comment: Hello, added detailed error trace.

Comment: Yes there is a package in pubspec called intercom.

Comment: Try removing this package just to know if that's the one causing the issue

Comment: got a long list of build errors after commenting out intercom in pub spec. Pratik has given a solution but i cant seem to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Comment codes corresponding to intercom. if that's the issue try upgrading the intercom package in pub spec.yaml file

Comment: Hi. Edited question with details. Updated intercom version. Getting a 'static' error now.

Comment: You have probably added static somevar = await Intercom.init. Can you verify with the latest doc on the initialisation

Comment: I'm importing intercom_flutter.dart in my file intercom.dart. The package link is https://github.com/v3rm0n/intercom_flutter/tree/master/intercom_flutter

Comment: From GitHub directly?

Comment: no from pubdev.https://pub.dev/packages/intercom_flutter

Comment: Please include your codewhere you added intercom functionalities

Comment: Done. Kindly check

Comment: Are you initialising it from main()?

Comment: Hi. Chekced Main. Cant find anything related to intercom. I'm using https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app an open source stack

Comment: Are you sending the correct ids?

Comment: I haven't registered with an app id yet since i just downloaded the repo and the error didn't seem related to ids

Comment: Try some test id. Should be available in their docs

Comment: Hi. I posted 1 out of 4 errors related to static. 1st 1 is initialize, Other 3 are displayMessenger, registerIdentifiedUser, logout.  All four are showing the same error that cannot be accessed using static access.

Comment: bootstrap where have you initialised this method?

Comment: Hi. Can't figure out about bootstrap. Can you help

Comment: Solved it. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to application tag in main folder AndroidManifest or fork the package you used and add it to package and push it back again to pub.dev :)

```
  <application>
    <receiver android:name="com.farsitel.bazaar.auth.receiver.AuthReceiver"
    android:exported="true">   
    </receiver>

  </application>
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved it by adding static to the methods being accessed in the core intercom_flutter package part of External libraries.